# Hide native scrollbar on iPhone using Javascript/css

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, dom-events, mobile-safari

I am trying to hide the scrollbar of my iPhone but `overflow: hidden` doesn't seem to be working. I also tried `touchmove(e) {e.preventDefault()}` but if I drag from down to up, I still see the scrollbar appear.
If I do `position: fixed`, then my page jumps (for example: if I open a modal view with my addressbar and nav bar minimized, on doing position: fixed, the address bar and nav bar appears back causing a jump on the page.)
Any advice would be appreciated.

I have also tried adding the styling for the scrollbars like:

```
.hide-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
  width: 0px;
  background: transparent;  
}

.hide-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
  display: none;
}

.hide-scrollbar {
  -ms-overflow-style: none;  // IE 10+
  overflow: -moz-scrollbars-none;  // Firefox
}
```

but still doesn't hide the scrollbar.